# Are we still in the Solar Maximus stage? Will this winter 2013/14 be a good aurora-viewing season?

Tags: light, solar-flare, coronal-mass-ejection

I remember reading in 2011 that 2013/2014 would be the peak of the current solar maximus, but I want to confirm whether that is still ongoing.  Will the upcoming winter season be a good time to see the Northern Lights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this data here:

http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/SolarCycle/

http://solarscience.msfc.nasa.gov/SunspotCycle.shtml

We are in a local maximum but the actual values have been lower than predicted for this time.

As for getting an idea for the aurora, I would keep an eye on the sunspot numbers and the space weather.

http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/today.html

http://www.gi.alaska.edu/AuroraForecast